# Expression of type Right[Nothing, Map[String, String]] doesn't conform to expected type Left[String, Nothing]

Tags: scala

I have the following code, that does not compile:

```
object PcpProtocol {

  private type PcpKV = String

  private val findPublicKey: List[PcpKV] => Either[String, Map[String, String]] = kv =>
    kv
      .filter(_.contains("PUBLIC:"))
      .foldLeft(Left("Can not find the public key from SAP.")) { (_, a) =>
        a.split(":").toList match {
          case List(key, value) => Right(Map(key -> value))
        }

      }
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.util.Right[Nothing,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]
[error]  required: scala.util.Left[String,Nothing]
[error]           case List(key, value) => Right(Map(key -> value))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can help compiler by specifying type explicitly.

```
  private val findPublicKey: List[PcpKV] => Either[String, Map[String, String]] = kv =>
    kv
      .filter(_.contains("PUBLIC:"))
      .foldLeft[Either[String, Map[String, String]]](Left("Can not find the public key from SAP.")) { (_, a) =>
        a.split(":").toList match {
           case List(key, value) => Right(Map(key -> value))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler can't infer type `Either[String, Map[String, String]]` correctly because it narrows it to `Left[String]`.

You can add type explicitily:

```
.foldLeft(Left("Can not find the public key from SAP."): Either[String, Map[String, String]]) { (_, a) =>
```

or:

```
.foldLeft[Either[String, Map[String, String]]](Left("Can not find the public key from SAP.")) { (_, a) =>
```

If you use cats in your project you could also use:

```
"Can not find the public key from SAP.".asLeft[Map[String, String]]
```

It often a good idea to create type alias for either, like:

```
type ErrorOr[T] = Either[String, T]
```

which could give you a little bit more readability:

```
.foldLeft[ErrorOr[Map[String, String]]]
```